# Dart - Flutter - How to assign a class object property to the color of a container widget

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, containers

im new to programming and I wanted to assign a class property to a flutter container widget's color.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
  child: Container(
    width: 4,
    height: 50,
    color: Colors.driver.color,
  ),
),
```

I tried to do this but instead it shown an error

```
The getter 'driver' isn't defined for the type 'Colors'.
```

This is from the models file

```
color: 'blue[800]',
```

If i use it in a text widget it works perfectly

```
Text(
  driver.points,
  style: TextStyle(
  fontSize: 16,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
  ),
),
```

Comment: Is ```driver.color``` not sufficient? If not, could you share the models file content using ```gist```.

Answer (score 0):

`Colors` is a class which holds predefined colors. This class has no getter or method named `driver`.

I guess you store a color in your model with an instance named `driver`. Therefore it should be:

```dart
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
  child: Container(
    width: 4,
    height: 50,
    color: driver.color,
  ),
),
```

Comment: It still gave me this error. The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'.

Comment: Instead of assigning the string `'blue[800]'` to the `color` attribute of `driver`, you should assign an instance of `Color`. For example `Colors.blue`.

Comment: ive tried it , but it still gave me the same exact error

Comment: Can you update your question and also post the content of the model file?